# Is there anyway to make this code in a range function so I don't have to repeat 100 times?

Tags: python-3.x, range

I am making a program to draw using 'x' but for each input, im going to have to copy out:

```
if input() == 'a0':
    L0[1] = 'x'
    print('\n')
    all()
```

100 times, then even another 100 if I want to add a way to delete the 'x',
is there any way to shorten that process using the range function or anything?

```
Tl = ['/','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
L0 = ['0','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']
L1 = ['1','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']
L2 = ['2','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']
L3 = ['3','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']
L4 = ['4','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']
L5 = ['5','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']
L6 = ['6','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']
L7 = ['7','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']
L8 = ['8','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']
L9 = ['9','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']
def all():
    print(*Tl)
    print(*L0)
    print(*L1)
    print(*L2)
    print(*L3)
    print(*L4)
    print(*L5)
    print(*L6) 
    print(*L7)
    print(*L8)
    print(*L9)
all()
print('\nenter coordinates to draw')
if input() == 'a0':
    L0[1] = 'x'
    print('\n')
    all()
```

I have thought about this and searched, but I have no clue how I am going to do this, thanks

Comment: Well, repeating it 100 times is certainely not the solution. Have you tried looking into loops and arrays?

Comment: You should split the data from the printing headers

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments above, you should split printing information from data storage.

The first approach would be creating a `list` of `list`s.

```
def create_empty_table():
    return [
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
    ]

def print_table(table):
    print("/ a b c d e f g h i j")
    for n, line in enumerate(table):
        print(n, " ".join(line))
    print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    table = create_empty_table()
    # The following part should probably go inside a loop to let the users introduce several values and not just one
    print_table(table)
    user_value = input("Enter coordinates to draw: ")  # Ask the user for the input
    letter = user_value[0]  # Extract the first char
    number = user_value[1]  # Extract the second char
    col = ord(letter) - ord("a")  # Transform the letter into an integer
    row = int(number)  # Transform the numbr into an int
    table[row][col] = 'x'
    print_table(table)
```

A numeric string can be converted to a int directly with `int('0')` but the letters are a bit more complex. The [builtin `ord` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) returns the unicode point representation of a character. By substracting the unicode point representation of `'a'` (97) we get an index that we can use in our lists: `ord('a') - ord('a') == 0`, `ord('b') - ord('a') == 1`, `ord('c') - ord('a') == 2`, ...

There are several things that could be enhanced. EDITING ...

Accepting capital letters is quite easy. Check the [`str.lower` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) if you want to try it yourself or continue with next example as it use this approach.

Non-hardcoded size for the table would be another improvement. For now we will keep the maximum number of rows and columns at 10 and 26 respectively as there are 10 digits and 26 letters. Accepting higher upper bounds will be done later on.

Another important variation is handling user input. We are going to use exceptions for this.

```
def create_empty_table(rows=10, cols=10, *, fill_char='.'):
    table = []
    for i in range(rows):                 # Create the specified number of rows
        table.append([fill_char] * cols)  # and the specified number of cols
    return table

def print_table(table):
    if len(table) == 0:  # If the table had no row and no column
        return           # we return to avoid errors
    header = "/"
    for i in range(ord("a"), ord("a") + len(table[0]):  # len(table[0]) == number of cols
        header += " " + chr(i)
    print(header)
    for n, line in enumerate(table):
        print(n, " ".join(line))
    print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    table = create_empty_table()
    # The following part should probably go inside a loop to let the users introduce several values and not just one
    print_table(table)
    while True:
        user_value = input("Enter coordinates to draw: ")  # Ask the user for the input
        try:
            letter = user_value[0]  # Extract the first char
            number = user_value[1]  # Extract the second char
        except IndexError:  # The user did not introduce two characters
            print("ERRROR: use 'a0' notation to introduce the coordinates!")
            continue  # Go back to the beggining of the loop again

        col = ord(letter.lower()) - ord("a")  # Transform the letter into an integer
        row = int(number)  # Transform the numbr into an int
        try:
            table[row][col] = 'x'
        except IndexError:  # He introduced wrong values
            print("ERROR: Wrong input!")
            continue

        break  # Get out of the while True infinite loop if we have gotten this far
    print_table(table)
```

The [builtin `chr` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) is the opposite of `ord`, it returns the symbol from the point (integer).

Some further verification would be needed for a robust code such as detecting if the first character is not a letter or the second is not a digit, detecting if he introduced more than 2 characters, ...

Comment: @dovlowinger I personally would suggest going for an OOP (object-oriented programming: classes, methods, etc.) approach, but as for your code you seem to be starting with Python so will keep the concepts simple for now. If you want to try the OOP approach answer to this comment and I'll give you some hints.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If you are already importing pandas somewhere in your code, you CAN leverage it to solve your current query.
If you are just starting a larger program which performs data crunching/analysis or deals with matrix, you MIGHT want to check panda's capabilities.
If your case is neither of above, then go with [Adirio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49315925/9501564)

Using pandas we have created a dataframe which is like a modifiable matrix. We initially populate it with '.' & later change them to 'x' as usr input arrives.
I have written this program to accept multiple fields to be changed to 'x' as long as they are separated by whitespace.
you can further modify this program to modify this matrix by as many types of symbols you want.

```
import pandas as pd

canvas = pd.DataFrame()
for z in 'abcdefghij':
    canvas = pd.concat([canvas,pd.DataFrame(['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],columns=list(z))],axis=1)

print('\nenter coordinates to draw')
usr_input = input()

for i in usr_input.split():
    c,r = list(i)
    r = int(r)
    canvas.at[r,c] = 'x'

print('\n')
print(canvas)
```

output:

```
enter coordinates to draw
a1 b2 c3

   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
0  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
1  x  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
2  .  x  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
3  .  .  x  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
4  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
5  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
6  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
7  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
8  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
9  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

Comment: I really think that `pandas` and `numpy` are two of the most powerful Python libraries and still they are the two that are worse used. If you use `pandas` in your script for another justified case go ahead and use it here too, but only importing this library for this part is completely ridiculous.

Comment: 1. Let the person who queried decide what is ridiculous or not. In any case this approach can only complement what other folks might answer. It might help in case if this person is just starting to write his 'larger' code or is already sourcing pandas.

Comment: You are right with the `list` part, my bad, just read it diagonally. Removed downvote. If you read my comment, I said that if you are already using `pandas` its fine to go this route. I only called ridiculous to import a heavy library as `pandas` if the only use was this. Your comment states more or less the same, but your answer does not, you directly suggest `pandas`. The OP author may read the comments here or not, but you can not rely on him reading the comments to get this part of the info. I suggest you include it into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it by storing only the "painted" coords in a set - or go for a dictionary and also store whats paintet at that coord.

Essentially you store only where/which players/coords are occupied. If a coord is not occupied, draw an "empty" in your grid, else draw its content:

Example for Player-turn-taking field:

```
  import os # clear console

  def cls():
      """Clears the console."""
      os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

  # playground definitions
  cols = [x for x in "abcdefghij"]     # column headers
  rows = [x for x in range(10)]        # row "headers"
  rowsString = [str(x) for x in rows]  # convenience

  # dictionary holding whats in what cell
  field = {}

  def printAll(d):
    """Clears the screen, prints d. Non-provided keys are printed as '.'""" 
    cls()
    print("   ", ' '.join(cols))        # print column headers 
    for rowNum in rows:
      print(f' {rowNum:d} ', end = " ") # print row header
      for c in cols:
        key = (c,rowNum)                # check if in dict, print value else '.'
        if key in d:
          print(f'{d[key]}', end = " ")
        else:
          print(".", end = " ")
      print()

  player = ["X","O"]
  turn = 0
  while True:
    printAll(field)     # inital field printing
    p = player[turn%2]  # who is it this turn?
    coord = ""
    print("'q' quits, 'r' resets")

    # repeat until valid input
    while len(coord)!= 2 or coord[0] not in cols or coord[1] not in rowsString:
      coord = input(f'Player {p} - enter coords: ')
      if coord=="q":
        exit()
      elif coord =="r":
        field = {}
        printAll(field)
        print("'q' quits, 'r' resets")
      elif len(coord)== 2 and (coord[0],int(coord[1])) in field:
        print("Already placed. Choose new coords.")
        coord=""

    # store coord with players symbol - if you only draw lines, simplify code w/o playrs
    field[(coord[0],int(coord[1]))] = p
    turn+=1
```

Output after some turns:

```
    a b c d e f g h i j
 0  . . . . . . . . . .
 1  . . . . . . . . . .
 2  . . . . . . . . . .
 3  . O X . . O . . . .
 4  X . . . . X . . . .
 5  X . . . . O . . . .
 6  . . . . . . . . . .
 7  . . . . . . . . . .
 8  . . . . . . . . X .
 9  O . O . . . . . . .
'q' quits, 'r' resets
Player X - enter coords: c99
Player X - enter coords: b33
Player X - enter coords: abdc
Player X - enter coords: hallo
Player X - enter coords: 34
Player X - enter coords:
```

---

To just print Xs and remove them again change the main program to:

```
while True:
  printAll(field) # inital field printing
  coord = ""
  print("'q' quits, 'r' resets")
  while len(coord)!= 2 or coord[0] not in cols or coord[1] not in rowsString:
    coord = input(f'Enter coords: ')
    if coord=="q":
      exit()
    elif coord =="r":
      field = {}
      printAll(field)
      print("'q' quits, 'r' resets")

  # set or delete field depending on if it is already set or not:
  if len(coord)== 2 and (coord[0],int(coord[1])) in field:
    field.pop((coord[0],int(coord[1])))
  else:
    field[(coord[0],int(coord[1]))] = 'X'
```